# getting weird symbols from yql

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql

I'm requesting a website from yql using something like: `select * from html where url="http://www.somerandomsite.com"&format=json&callback=process`

The problem is I'm getting weird symbols back like: �

Is this because of yahoo or from the site that I'm using and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing a `<meta>` tag which defines the `charset`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: It's not my site, hence I'm using YQL

Comment: Right. Are you *displaying* the text on another site? They might be coming back right, but you are seeing them incorrectly.

Comment: they are using a charset of ISO-8859-1, is there a way to force it into unicode, or convert to unicode, I don't want to change my site's charset. It's mostly just apostrophes.